# Using buttons as field inputs instead of dropdown menu/radio buttons/check boxes.

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

On my form, I have a field with 7 possible values. Instead of using a dropdown menu or check boxes I would like to display the data on buttons, similar to Quirky.com's application form- specifically the 'Choose a Category' field (https://www.quirky.com/ideas/new).

Is this a jquery plugin?

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwVEX.png

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is not a specific plug for this specific functionality, however it would be very easy to do with jQuery. Simply create a field (text field will be fine) to hold the value that you want to submit, then create your 7 buttons. Create a simple javascript function to set the value of your textfield based on what button is clicked. Viola!

The function may look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(button){
$('#idOfTextBox').val(button.attr('name'));

$('.classOfButton').removeClass('selected');
button.addClass('selected');

return false;
}
<script>
```

Edit: script changes
You will notice I add and remove classes from the button and it's fellow buttons. This way you can style which one is selected. In addition, I use the "name" attribute of the button as it's value in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard HTML form tags, and then convert them into buttons. This is better as, if JavaScript is disabled, the user will still be able to use the form. This is 'graceful degradation'.

If the options are mutually exclusive, use radio buttons. If not, use checkboxes.

Code for such a technique can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff756526 and http://theodin.co.uk/blog/design/fancy-radio-buttons-jquery.html.